# Interval partitioning problem different approach - arrange lectures in minimum number of classrooms

Tags: algorithm, correctness

The problem of scheduling lectures in minimum number of classrooms is as follows: Find minimum number of classrooms to schedule all lecture so that no two occur at the same time in the same room.

The common algorithm that I find in books is:

```
Sort intervals by starting time so that s1 ≤ s2 ≤ ... ≤ sn.
d ← 0 //number of classrooms
for j = 1 to n {
 if (lecture j is compatible with some classroom k)
 schedule lecture j in classroom k
 else
 allocate a new classroom d + 1
 schedule lecture j in classroom d + 1
 d ← d + 1
}
```

Now, I was thinking of an alternate approach where I sort my lectures by finishing times in ascending order and every time I check if lecture j is compatible with some classroom k and there are multiple classrooms that are compatible with that lecture, I schedule it in the classroom which the last jobs finish time in that classroom is closest to that jobs start time, i.e minimise the time a classroom is empty.

```
Sort intervals by starting time so that f1 ≤ f2 ≤ ... ≤ fn.
d ← 0 //number of classrooms
for j = 1 to n {
 if (lecture j is compatible with some classroom k)
 schedule lecture j in classroom k which was used last
 else
 allocate a new classroom d + 1
 schedule lecture j in classroom d + 1
 d ← d + 1
}
```

I would like to know if this approach is right(not necessarily optimal). I have dry run it on a couple of cases, and looks to be okay. If yes, how can I prove its correctness? If not, how can what changes can I make the algorithm work.

Comment: how do you check the compatibility of interval with a classroom?

Comment: If lecture i and j, with start time and finish time (s(i),f(i)) and (s(j), f(j)) respectively are compatible then f(i)<s(j)

Comment: I didn't ask about compatibility of interval with another interval, I mean the interval with classroom, `if (lecture j is compatible with some classroom k)`, how do you find such a classroom?

Comment: If the classroom is empty at the time a lecture starts, then that classroom and lecture are compatible.

Comment: how do you find the empty classroom? your lectures are sorted by finish times. you start from the lecture with the earliest finish time and according to your pseudocode you have no classrooms yet. there could be a lecture with later finish time but earlier start time, and that lecture should already occupy one classroom.

Comment: conclusion: the lectures should be sorted by start times and `classroom compatible with lecture i` implies the classroom that contains only the lectures `j` with `f(j) < s(i)`. the first version is correct so no need to reinvent the wheel here

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It will work.
You have to maintain an array End[] which can tell you last class time of a classroom.
So, run a loop over your sorted array and for every lecture visit all the classrooms initialized already. If you have a classroom where End[classroom id] < start[current lecture] then you can use otherwise you have to initialize a new classroom. 
Another way is:
 
if you know minimum starting time and maximum ending time of all lectures independently. Then you have to run a loop from minimum starting time to maximum ending time and count how many lectures are held for the current time. maximum count among all i(minimum time <=i <= maximum time) is your answer.

Comment: `classroom where End[classroom id] < start[current lecture] then you can use otherwise you have to initialize a new classroom.` this is not enough to find the `smallest` number of classrooms

Comment: about `another way`: so what is the `current time` ? it is definitely neither start time nor finish time. then what time is it ? picking random time between start time and finish time is wrong - the maximum count may appear at any time moment between start and finish time. so `another way` is wrong

Comment: why do you have to pick a random number? I said run a loop from min time to max end time. means 1,2,3,4,5,6,....n.

Comment: yes, it is possible to find the minimum number of classrooms in that way. There is a problem in Uva online judge name: The Monkey and oil bamboo. the idea is something like that.

Comment: that works only if the start/finish time is integer. there is no requirement in conditions that the start/finish time should necessarily be an integer

Comment: it is not possible to find the minimum number of classrooms in a single array traversal. the first traversal will give the number of lectures for the 1st classroom, the second traversal will give the number of lectures for the 2nd classroom, etc. until no lectures remain

Comment: @AhsanShuvo Regarding my approach of sorting it by finish time, how do I prove the correctness?

Comment: @user3508140 it's unclear what do you want to prove. I already showed above that it is incorrect.  the first approach that he suggested (incomplete though) is totally different from your method.